# blockquote css not displaying properly in IE 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, sass

I'm using the "blockquote" element to add a quote on my website. Here's the code that I'm using:

```
blockquote {
  @extend .no-margin;

  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 60px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1em;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 3em;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: 300;
}

blockquote:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 20px;
  content: "\201C";
}

blockquote:after {
  top: 0;
  right: 20px;
  content: "\201D";
}
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<blockquote>
  Here's my quote
</blockquote>
```

That's the result in Safari/Chrome/Firefox/Edge:

[image]

and here's how it displays on Internet Explorer 11:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Looks like it's maybe calculating the font-size (ems) of the :before and :after differently, so possibly a CSS inheritance issue. Have you tried using a px or rem value instead, to see if they act the same?

Comment: According to https://caniuse.com/#search=content for IE 11 the `content` property is only partially supported: __"Partial support in Internet Explorer 10-11 refers to the browser only supporting the 'sandbox' directive by using the X-Content-Security-Policy header."__